# Conceptual questions on the ASP.NET MVC 3 and Entity Framework/MySQL interface

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I have now decided to try out ASP.NET MVC 3.
My host provider, however, only supports MySQL and therefore I have to figure out how to use MVC 3 with MySQL.

I have also decided that I don't wanna do any SQL code if I can avoid it, and I would also like O/RM without too much effort. I understand that the Entity Framework will actually help me accomplish this to a large extent.

I have been trying to get into the various ways of using the EF, with the database first, model first and code first approaches supplied by the framework.
So far, I have not had much luck, and I find that the examples available all use very different approaches that confuses me a lot.

I might begin by asking for guidance on getting a few concepts right.
First of all, the Model (in MVC) is actually more like a ViewModel, that represents something (Users, Posts, etc.) in terms of Properties is more or less simple classes. I.e. the model is where the data from the database gets mapped to an object (the O/RM). Am I right?

A repository is a wrapper that encapsulates a specific way of retrieving data for the models. For instance, a DatabaseRepository or a FakeTestRepository.
Should I have a single repository in my MVC project, or a repository per database table, such that I have a UsersRepository and PostsRepository?
Should the repository be a model for itself, not a model at all, or tied to individual models (so that UsersRepository is part of the UsersModel)?

I have tried to use the EF's model first approach, and for a simple test I just have created an empty model and added the entities "Author" and "Guide" that are related by a one-to-many relation.
When I then, in Visual Studio 2010, "Generate database from model", I get the corresponding sql code. I want this database to be created in MySQL. How can I accomplish that?

Are there some code examples for MVC 3 with MySQL and O/RM where the creation of a small site is demonstrated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning EF Model First approach: take a look at [this Tips & Tricks article](http://www.devart.com/blogs/dotconnect/index.php/entity-framework-tips-and-tricks-part-4.html#second). We have described this common situation in it (it is Oracle-specific, but [dotConnect for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql) contains the "Devart SSDLToMySQL.tt" template).
As for the rest of the questions - there is no definite answer. Choose the approach that suits you better.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, you should try the code first. And as you said that your host only provides MySQL you can also use MySQL database as a database I personally use MySQL. Concepts are the same but logic is different you have to code it a different way. But from my point of view, you can use MySQL as a database service.

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow, just a heads up, you are responding to a post that is 12 years old, and IMO the question itself is very specific to the original poster's situation and isn't relevant today.